# Gazebo 9 to 11 migration, wrong world coordinates and robot collapses

Tags: ros-noetic, gazebo-11

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

Hi,
I am trying to migrate a simulation from ROS melodic to noetic. In ROS melodic (gazebo 9) everything works as expected, but when launching it in noetic the world file models are completely out of place (the .world file was not modified). What is more the robot (holonomic platform) has its Lidars and kinect camera positions changed from correctly sitting on top of the platform to being inside the model. It is maybe connected to wrong inertia values of those components, but in gazebo 9 they seem to be working ( I didn't set those).
I've read through migration guide for gazebo 9 -> 11 and I couldn't find anything that would affect those behaviors. Does anyone know what maybe the cause of this problem?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.gazebosim.org/question/25593/gazebo-9-to-11-migration,-wrong-world-coordinates-and-robot-collapses./) by [redox](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/29326/redox/) on Gazebo Answers with karma: 16 on 2020-07-26

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [chapulina](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/1019/chapulina/) on 2020-07-27**:
Can you share a minimum SDF file to reproduce the problem? It could be related to the new SDF spec (1.7).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

Thank you for your reply, I did not know that the SDF version chaged between gazebo 9 and 11. The solution was to simply change version tag in world file from 1.6 to 1.7

---

Originally posted by [redox](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/29326/redox/) with karma: 16 on 2020-07-28

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0